# Finding orientation angles of end-effector from the DH parameter table and transformation matrices

Tags: forward-kinematics, dh-parameters, orientation, geometry

Let's say we have a manipulator with the following DH parameter table:
[image]
and transformation matrices:
$$A_{01}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(q_1) & \sin(q_1) & 0 & 95\cos(q_1)\\
\sin(q_1) & -\cos(q_1) & 0 & 95\sin(q_1)\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$A_{12}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(q_2) & 0 & \sin(q_2) & 89\cos(q_2)\\
\sin(q_2) & 0 & -\cos(q_2) & 89\sin(q_2)\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$A_{23}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(q_3) & -\sin(q_3) & 0 & 147\cos(q_3)\\
\sin(q_2) & \cos(q_2) & 0 & 147\sin(q_2)\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -28\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
When multiplied, they form the absolute transformation matrix of the end-effector relative to the reference frame:
$$A_{03}=A_{01}\cdot A_{12}\cdot A_{23}=$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(q_3)\cos(q_1-q_2) & -\sin(q_3)\cos(q_1-q_2) & -\sin(q_1-q_2) & 95\cos(q_1)+28\sin(q_1-q_2)+89\cos(q_1-q_2)+147\cos(q_3)\cos(q_1-q_2)\\
\cos(q_3)\sin(q_1-q_2) & -\sin(q_3)\sin(q_1-q_2) & \cos(q_1-q_2) & 95\sin(q_1)-28\cos(q_1-q_2)+89\sin(q_0-q_1)+147\cos(q_3)\sin(q_1-q_2)\\
-\sin(q_3) & -\cos(q_3) & 0 & -147\sin(q_3)\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
We can easily read the position of the end-effector relative to the reference frame just from the fourth column of the $A_{03}$ matrix:
$\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix} = $
$\begin{bmatrix}
95\cos(q_1)+28\sin(q_1-q_2)+89\cos(q_1-q_2)+147\cos(q_3)\cos(q_1-q_2)\\
95\sin(q_1)-28\cos(q_1-q_2)+89\sin(q_0-q_1)+147\cos(q_3)\sin(q_1-q_2)\\
-147\sin(q_3)
\end{bmatrix}$

How can we read the orientation of the end-effector relative to the reference frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $A_{0.3}$ matrix is a 4x4 transformation matrix. In a general form these 4x4 matrices can be subdivided into a 3x3 rotation and a 3x1 translation part. (The remaining parts can be used for scaling, but are not used in robotics)

$
A_{0,3}= T_{4 \times 4}=
\begin{pmatrix}
R_{3 \times 3} & T_{3  \times 1}\\
0_{1 \times  3} & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$

The $R_{3 \times 3}$ part is a 3x3 [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), also called a [direction cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine) matrix. Basically it is built from the coordinates of the unit vectors of the end effector coordinate system expressed in the reference coordinate system. [This](http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/%7Egslabaugh/publications/euler.pdf) guide describes how to convert this matrix to Euler angles.